# Open Bootstrap Modal from code-behind

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Anyone knows how to open a twitter bootstrap modal, from code behind?

I want to open the modal based on some requeriment at the moment of the save. Something like "Hey there's no stock, pick up one of the following options to continue (discard, reserve...) and press that button (that may do a postback for continue)"

I'm using ASP.NET web forms.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using, asp.net? Do you mean the code behind from the page where you want to show the modal?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: No one knows why "ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock([GetType], "none", "$('#MyModal').show();", True)" does not work??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I found out the problem preventing me from showing the modal from code-behind.
One must think that it was as easy as register a clientscript that made the opening, like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),"none",
    "<script>$('#mymodal').modal('show');</script>", false);
```

But this never worked for me.

The problem is that **Twitter Bootstrap Modals scripts don't work at all when the modal is inside an asp:Updatepanel**, period.
The behaviour of the modals fail from each side, codebehind to client and client to codebehind (postback). It even prevents postbacks when any js of the modal has executed, like a close button that you also need to do some sever objects disposing (for a dirty example)

I've notified the bootstrap staff, but they replied a convenient "please give us a fail scenario with only plain html and not asp."
In my town, that's called... well, Bootstrap not supporting anything more that plain html. Nevermind, using it on asp.

I thought them to at least looking what they're doing different at the backdrop management, that I found causes the major part of the problems, but... (justa hint there)

So anyone that has the problem, drop the updatepanel for a try.

Answer (score 47):

By default Bootstrap javascript files are included just before the closing body tag

```
        <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>
 </body>
```

I took these javascript files into the head section right before the body tag and I wrote a small function to call the modal popup:

```
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

then I could call the modal popup from code-behind with the following:

```
protected void lbEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop", "openModal();", true);
}
```

Comment: This just saved me many lines of code.  I was using asp:hidden fields and setting values in the hidden fields.  When the page loaded, I'd evaluate the hidden fields to determine if the js should pop open the dialogue. Thank you for this.  I have some cleaning up to do!

Comment: In the "lblEdit_Click" event, I did not have the option for "ScriptManager" in my intellisense.
I realize this is a very old thread butt would hope there was a workaround for this.

Comment: I found my own solution:
Solution:  Make sure Using System.Web.UI; is being referenced.

Comment: This is working for me, but the screen flashes for a brief second then the drop down emerges.  Any way to get rid of the flashing?

Comment: Using VS 2019...All I did was put the JS at the bottom of the ASP page and the RegisterStartupScript in the code behind. That's it.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this answer is so late, but it's useful.
to do it,we have 3 steps:
1- Create a modal structure in HTML.
2- Create a button to call a function in java script, to open modal and set `display:none` in CSS .
3- Call this button by function in code behind .
you can see these steps in below snippet :

HTML modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                Registration done Successfully</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal -->
```

Hidden Button:

```
<button type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnShowPopup" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>
```

Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPopup() {
            $("#btnShowPopup").click();
        }
    </script>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
    this.lblMessage.Text = "Your Registration is done successfully. Our team will contact you shotly";
}
```

this solution is one of any solutions that I used it .

Answer (score 1):

This method of opening the Modal would not display the Modal for me. I found this as a work arround.

I removed:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"Pop", "openModal();", true);
```

Than I added an asp:label named lblJavaScript and in code behind call:

```
lblJavaScript.Text = "<script language=\"JavaScript\">openModal()</script>";
```

Now the Modal will display.

Answer (score 1):

All of the example above should work just add a document ready action and change the order of how you perform the updates to the texts, also make sure your using Script manager alternatively non of this will work for you. Here is the text within the code behind.

aspx

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind

```
lblModalTitle.Text = "Validation Errors";
lblModalBody.Text = form.Error;
upModal.Update();
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$(document).ready(function () {$('#myModal').modal();});", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this:

1) show popup with form

2) submit form using AJAX

3) in AJAX server side code, render response that will either:

- show popup with form with validations or just a message
- close the popup (and maybe redirect you to new page)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's not clearly a validation, but what you say will do. Anyway, when you say:
"show popup with form" and "close the popup"
Yes, those are my problems, open and close from codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

I've seen this strange behavior before in jQuery widgets.  Part of the key is to put the updatepanel inside the modal.  This allows the DOM of the updatepanel to "stay with" the modal (however it works with bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

This line worked for me to open Bootstrap Modal behind code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "randomText", "$(document).ready(function () {$('#myModal').modal();});", true);
```