# Closing bootstrap modal from server if validation passes

Tags: asp.net, validation, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Simply stated, I want to have ASP validations fire for my button in my bootstrap modal. If the validations fire, I want them to appear without the modal closing. If the validations don't fire, the modal closes normally.

I've checked out a lot of solutions for this but I don't think I've found one that works quite yet. I want to use ASP validations on one of the text boxes in the bootstrap modal. If I have data-dismiss="modal" on my button, the modal will close even if the validation fires.

In my mind, it would work best if I could close the modal from the server side. But I'm not sure if there are better solutions. Here's my clientside code for the footer:

```
   <div class="modal-footer">  
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitMessageBtn" Text="Send" class="btn btn-success" OnClick="SubmitMessageBtn_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
    </div>
```

And here's what I've attempted on the server side:

```
 protected void SubmitMessageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if validation passes
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Hide", "<script> $('#messageUserModal').modal('hide');</script>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the issue here: 
[Open Bootstrap Modal from code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410232/open-bootstrap-modal-from-code-behind)

Apparently it doesn't work if it's in a update panel

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is an older thread. The RegisterStartUp will register the script before the init. Try using something like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, GetType(), "HideLoginDialog", "<script> $('#login-dialog').modal('hide');</script>", false);
```

the markup should look like

```
<div id="login-dialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
...
            <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up_login">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="login" OnClick="login_Click" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Login"></asp:Button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
...
</div>
```

the code behind will look like

```
protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseModalServerEvent();
}

protected void CloseModalServerEvent()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, GetType(), "HideLoginDialog", "<script> $('#login-dialog').modal('hide');</script>", false);
}
```