# show the bootstrap modal from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I created an ASP.NET Web Application (webforms) using visual studio 2013. bootstrap has been created and working properly.

my plan is to show a modal dialog which work perfectly as below using data-target attribute:

```
<div id="confimDialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Your request has been submitted successfully.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" data-target="#confirmDialog" />
```

When I moved to the next step to show the confirmation from code behind, after executing some update in my database, the modal dialog never showed up:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //my database codes here
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "Confirm();", true);
}
```

and for sure I added the following script to my aspx page:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
<script>
    function Confirm () {
        $('#confirmDialog').modal('show'); 
        return true;
    };
</script>
```

I spent two days in this problem without any solution... I saw that there are some problem in showing a modal dialog from code behind, while many people say it's working using this codes.
could you please help in this or propose any alternative solution to show a confirmation dialog from code behind???

**references:**
[bootstrap modal problem in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410232/open-bootstrap-modal-from-code-behind)

thanks.

Comment: Javascript called or not?

Comment: Add your code behind this..."Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","Confirm()",true);"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410232/open-bootstrap-modal-from-code-behind This might help

Answer (score 2):

I figured  out that if you move this two lines to the top ( inside the header ) it works,

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

most of the people recommend put this two lines at the end, before the body ends, but I moved them to the header and it works.