# Open bootstrap modal from codebehind crashes tooltips

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I build asp webform page (vb.net) 
My tooltips crashes when I open modal from code behind using below code

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            sb.Append('&ltscript type='text/javascript'&gt')
            sb.Append('$('#SetTime').modal('show');')
            sb.Append('&lt/script&gt')
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.[GetType](), 'SetTimeModalScript', sb.ToString(), False)
```

If I open the same modal form using button eg.

```
&ltbutton type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SetTime"&gt Launch demo modal
&lt/buton&gt
```

everything works fine.

To initialize tooltips I use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('[data-tooltip="true"]').tooltip();
});
```

I try to find solution but I gave up after few hours.

I must use this code to open modal because I open it to display data for specific gridview row.

**Edit**

Here is part of code where I put data tooltip :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="SetTime" data-tooltip="true" title="Ustaw czas rozpoczęcia i zakończenia zlecenia" data-container="body"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> </asp:LinkButton>
```

I tried also with `data-target="tooltip" instead data-tooltip="true"`

Comment: where you are put [data-tooltip="true"] ??

Comment: Refer this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410232/open-bootstrap-modal-from-code-behind

Comment: Here is part of code where I put data tooltip : <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="SetTime"
                                 data-tooltip="true" title="Ustaw czas rozpoczęcia i zakończenia zlecenia" data-container="body">
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            </asp:LinkButton>  I tried also with data-target="tooltip" instead data-tooltip="true"