# how do i stop refreshing page in bootstrap modal with asp.net button click

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to show data in modal view of bootstrap, the data is retrieved from the database. The problem is it shows the data but for a fraction of second and the page gets refreshed automatically. 
this is my html

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left: 5px;">
 <br />
 Invoice #<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Invoiceno" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_showInvoice" runat="server" OnClick="ShowUserPass_Click" OnClientClick="showModel()">Show Last Five Invoices</asp:LinkButton>
 </div>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Last five invoices </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvInvoices"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my .cs file

```
protected void ShowUserPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLHelper objSql = new SQLHelper();
    objSql.SqlText = "select FirstName,LastName,Email from tblUserDetail";
    DataTable dt = objSql.getDataTable(false);
    gvInvoices.DataSource = dt;
    gvInvoices.DataBind();
    objSql.Close();
    objSql.Dispose();

}
```

jquery:

```
 <script>
    function showModel() {
        $('.modal').modal();
    }

</script>
```

So my question is, how do i stop the page refreshing automatically?

Comment: Can you please try by using simple button or othere element rather tha link button?

Comment: yeah i tried that too.

Answer (score 3):

try below code by changing both ASP code and script

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_showInvoice" runat="server" OnClick="ShowUserPass_Click" OnClientClick="showModel(); return false">Show Last Five Invoices</asp:LinkButton>


    <script>
        function showModel() {
            $('.modal').modal();

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: sory i forgot to add retutn false now try to change code as mentioned in aswer

Comment: it did not reload the page by doing these, but the data which needs to be binded is not showing at all.

Comment: just try to add autopostback="false" and remove return statement from my code, just call OnClientClick="showModel()"

Comment: sorry @jekin, i have already tried that but donot work, actually the data do come at second click but not at first click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410232/open-bootstrap-modal-from-code-behind   might help to you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply stop refreshing or submitting by adding **return false**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_showInvoice" runat="server" OnClick="ShowUserPass_Click" OnClientClick="showModel();return false;">Show Last Five Invoices</asp:LinkButton>
```

You can add like this , this should fix your issue.

Else You Can use ajax.

Comment: can u ellaborate? @sherin.k

Comment: please read edited replay @Roal.A  If the problem is still not solved , comment here  the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. using ajax it solved

html

```
 <a OnClick="showModel()" >Show Last Five Invoices</a>
```

Jquery

```
   function showModel() {
   $('.modal').modal();


    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "filename.aspx/ShowUserPass_Click",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "jsondata",
    async: "true",
    success: function (t) {
         //set value to gridview or use normal table
    },
    error: function (t) { }
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Such problem happens when you are using input type submit but that's not valid for this case.

**The second reason is you are using an anchor having a blank href in it. And I think this is happening with you.**

To overcome with this problem we can use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="..." class="...">Link</a>
```

This will not redirect or refresh the page, just act like a button.

Comment: where do u trigger ShowUserPass_Click.cs by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UpdatePanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) as below:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mdlShowUserPass">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Your Content. Ex form
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Surround the '`modal-content`' class with an UpdatePanel control. You can also open the modal from code behind using the scriptmanager like below.

```
protected void ShowUserPass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLHelper objSql = new SQLHelper();
    objSql.SqlText = "select FirstName,LastName,Email from tblUserDetail";
    DataTable dt = objSql.getDataTable(false);
    gvInvoices.DataSource = dt;
    gvInvoices.DataBind();
    objSql.Close();
    objSql.Dispose();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "", "<script>$(function () {$('#mdlShowUserPass').modal({show:true,keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static'});});</script>", false); 
    // note the #mdlShowUserPass id which assigned to the modal
}
```

If you wish to close the modal from server side, add a `LinkButton` and assign a click event, use the scriptmanager again to hide the modal by changing to `show:false` from true.

### Edit

**I missunderstood your question. If you want to prevent the modal from closing when pressing a button inside the modal, for ex, submit the modal, etc., you can use the aforesaid solution.**

**However, if you want to open the modal after postback, you can just add the scriptmanager line to the linkbutton click event. No need to add updatepanel to the modal.**

Comment: can u please provide me the code, i ve put the return false statement as everybody has suggested
By doing so, the page do not refresh it works, but the data donot bind it shows empty.

Comment: Remove any scripts that you used in the page as suggested by others and remove your script (onClientClick event) also. replace the c# code with the aforesaid code (click event) which has the script that will open the modal after postback.

Comment: thnx, the data is retrieved but the modal keeps on popping even on the refresh button.

Comment: yes, pressing F5 button will reload the modal since the page is postbacked from the server.

Comment: so, how do i prevent it? i've tried `AutoPostBack=false` but the modal pops on refresh